# fancyhdr style problem

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am having some problems with the `fancyhdr` package. How can I achieve the following in my big thesis file:
The header should consists of the chapter name at the left side and the page number at the right side. The page with number 1 should be the first page of the first chapter. 
The "fancy" style should start after the table of contents and everything before should be enumerated with the letter i, ii and so on.

Comment: Are you using `twoside`? What document class are you using?

Comment: I am using \documentclass[leqno,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the following MWE I've created two different page styles: `frontmatter` and `mainmatter`. Your typical document structure will most likely include resetting the page style between these document components, including a call to `\frontmatter`/`mainmatter` to reset the page number and presentation (`\roman` and `\arabic`) as well as other ToC-related stuff:

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}% Chapter in header Left
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Page number in header Right
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter%
\pagestyle{frontmatter}% frontmatter page style
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1-20]% Some dummy text

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}%
\pagestyle{mainmatter}% mainmatter page style
\lipsum[1-20]% Some dummy text
\end{document}
```

You don't mention any [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-compatibility requirement. However, that could also be incorporated.

Comment: Why not using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` instead of the `\pagenumbering` commands? You may include the page style choice in them. In this way you don't need `\chapter*` and `\chapter{Preface}` will not provide a number, but will make a TOC entry automatically.

Comment: I have one small problem. The first chapter after the contents is the intruduction. I used \chapter*{Introduction}. How can I make sure this appears also in the list of contents (without a number).

Comment: @Nadori: Use `\chapter*{Introduction} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`. I would also suggest adding another page style (say, `introduction`) that provides clears `L`eft header of `\leftmark`, otherwise you'll see "CHAPTER 0. Preface". With the other page styles created, it should be no problem to figure out what you want `introduction` to contain.